# Minimization of L1-Regularized system, converging on non-minimum location?

Tags: matlab, optimization, machine-learning, minimization, convex-optimization

This is my first post to stackoverflow, so if this isn't the correct area I apologize. I am working on minimizing a L1-Regularized System.

This weekend is my first dive into optimization, I have a basic linear system Y = X*B, X is an n-by-p matrix, B is a p-by-1 vector of model coefficients and Y is a n-by-1 output vector.

I am trying to find the model coefficients, I have implemented both gradient descent and coordinate descent algorithms to minimize the L1 Regularized system. To find my step size I am using the backtracking algorithm, I terminate the algorithm by looking at the norm-2 of the gradient and terminating if it is 'close enough' to zero(for now I'm using 0.001).

The function I am trying to minimize is the following (0.5)*(norm((Y - X*B),2)^2) + lambda*norm(B,1). (Note: By norm(Y,2) I mean the norm-2 value of the vector Y) My X matrix is 150-by-5 and is not sparse.

If I set the regularization parameter lambda to zero I should converge on the least squares solution, I can verify that both my algorithms do this pretty well and fairly quickly.

If I start to increase lambda my model coefficients all tend towards zero, this is what I expect, my algorithms never terminate though because the norm-2 of the gradient is always positive number. For example, a lambda of 1000 will give me coefficients in the 10^(-19) range but the norm2 of my gradient is ~1.5, this is after several thousand iterations,  While my gradient values all converge to something in the 0 to 1 range, my step size becomes extremely small (10^(-37) range). If I let the algorithm run for longer the situation does not improve, it appears to have gotten stuck somehow.

Both my gradient and coordinate descent algorithms converge on the same point and give the same norm2(gradient) number for the termination condition. They also work quite well with lambda of 0. If I use a very small lambda(say 0.001) I get convergence, a lambda of 0.1 looks like it would converge if I ran it for an hour or two, a lambda any greater and the convergence rate is so small it's useless.

I had a few questions that I think might relate to the problem?

In calculating the gradient I am using a finite difference method (f(x+h) - f(x-h))/(2h)) with an h of 10^(-5). Any thoughts on this value of h?

Another thought was that at these very tiny steps it is traveling back and forth in a direction nearly orthogonal to the minimum, making the convergence rate so slow it is useless.

My last thought was that perhaps I should be using a different termination method, perhaps looking at the rate of convergence, if the convergence rate is extremely slow then terminate. Is this a common termination method?

Comment: I am not suggesting this is offtopic for StackOverflow, but it might be an even better fit for http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @tmyklebu: Perhaps a better fit for Programmers.stackexchange.com though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 1-norm isn't differentiable.  This will cause fundamental problems with a lot of things, notably the termination test you chose; the gradient will change drastically around your minimum and fail to exist on a set of measure zero.

The termination test you really want will be along the lines of "there is a very short vector in the [subgradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative)."

It is fairly easy to find the shortest vector in the subgradient of ||Ax-b||_2^2 + lambda ||x||_1.  Choose, wisely, a tolerance `eps` and do the following steps:

1. Compute `v = grad(||Ax-b||_2^2).`
2. If `x[i] < -eps`, then subtract lambda from `v[i]`.  If `x[i] > eps`, then add lambda to `v[i]`.  If `-eps <= x[i] <= eps`, then add the number in `[-lambda, lambda]` to `v[i]` that minimises `v[i]`.

You can do your termination test here, treating `v` as the gradient.  I'd also recommend using `v` for the gradient when choosing where your next iterate should be.